# C# Faceted Search Remove selected option where duplicates keys names exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm working on a faceted search system and need help.

I have a form which allows you to filter by location using checkboxes:

[image]

If I check both Italy and Spain and submit the form, all the matching locations are fetched from the db and the url looks like this:

```
/mywebsite/index.aspx?location=Italy&location=Spain
```

The next bit i'm trying to code, and stuck on, is removing an individual location by having a red x hyperlink beside it, so here i would attempt to delete Spain:

[image]

I have tried using the following code but it removes all instances of location from the url!  So both Spain and Italy are deleted instead of just spain...

```
NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query);
nvc.Remove("location");
```

I can loop through the querystring and compair each key against "location" and key value against my db value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nvc.Count; i++)
{
    if ( (nvc.Keys[i] == "location") && (nvc[i].Contains(locationFromDB)) )
    {

        Response.Write("<p>Found location " + locationFromDB + " in " + nvc.Keys[i] + " - " + nvc[i] + "</p>");

    }                                
}
```

which results in

```
Found location Spain in location - Italy,Spain
```

I'm just not sure what the code should be to delete the single instance of location in the outputted url?

can anyone help?

Comment: i think your url's query string causes undefined behavior

Comment: @ragerory unfortunately that's what the querystring looks like after you submit a form with mulitple checkboxes.

Comment: Could you put the remove within the loop where you have response.